# Showing both Windows installations in grub (single Windows EFI partition)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I hope this is the right place to ask this question!

I have a machine in which I have three OSs installed: two Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

The two windows 10 systems have been installed on the same drive, share the same EFI partition, and appear as a single entry in my grub. When I select that entry, I get to the Windows boot menu, in which I have to choose if I want to boot one or the other version.

My grub menu looks like this (picture taken from the internet)

[image]

My windows boot menu looks like this, only with Windows1 and Windows2 as options instead (picture taken from the internet)

[image]
If I select version  1 I get directly to the desktop without issues, but if I select version 2 the machine reboots and I have to go through the grub menu all over again. When I was using version 1 more often this wouldn't be a problem, but lately I am using version 2 a lot more: I now need to make sure I'm switching to windows in the grub twice and select version 2 in the windows boot menu, which is quite cumbersome.

Now, since there's a single Windows EFI partition, I can't seem to make both installations visible in the grub, and would like to know if there's some way of fixing my problem! The output for the windows entry in the grub is the following:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  5A8C-8F53
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5A8C-8F53
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

I know that Windows does something like setting a parameter or similar in order to get to windows version 2, as I need to choose the grub entry twice but on the second boot it skips the windows boot menu.

This is my GParted view of the Windows drive:

[image]

I hope I was clear, happy to add more details if needed!

Comment: @darth_epoxy I can boot into efi no problem, I want to have Windows v1, Windows v2, and ubuntu on my grub menu

Comment: That's not how it works. Whenever you install different Windows version one of them will have control over booting and Grub will only see this bootloader.